# li::before pseudo element not being applied

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a simple UL list that I am applying a CSS class too and the li::before pseudo class is not being applied.

HTML

```
<ul class="my-ul">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.my-ul {
    font-size: 12pt;
    list-style: none;
}

.my-ul li {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.my-ul li::before {
    content: disc;
    color: #501521;
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is `disc`? Changing it to `'x'` works, so the issue is with `disc`, not `::before`: https://plnkr.co/edit/QHxhrtPan8xkyceYxY6y?p=preview

Comment: You probably wanted  `.my-ul li {list-style-type: disc}` (?)

Comment: @myf The li element is showing up but the color is not being applied to the li element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are probably looking for the special char `u+2022`

```css
.my-ul {
  font-size: 12pt;
  list-style: none;
}

.my-ul li {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.my-ul li::before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="my-ul">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks - now I want to adjust the size and increase the right padding of the li element